# Delayed dialog with resume handler

Tags: botframework

I have the following scenario I think I'm doing it wrong.

I have a `RootDialog` which calls a `ResultDialog`. The `ResultDialog` presents the user a list of results (using `HeroCard`).

The ResultDialog closes itself using `context.Done(..)` after the message was posted.

In the RootDialog- `AfterResultDialog` Resume handler I want to ask the user if he has found the matching result, using another dialog (`NotificationDialog`), but I want to do that after 30 seconds.

After some research, this seems like it must be done using proactive messages.
It this [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages/startNewDialogWithPrompt), I found a way to post the `NotificationDialog` in a proactive way.

```
private async Task AfterResultDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    var message = await result as IMessageActivity;

    var conversationReference = context.Activity.ToConversationReference();
    ConversationStarter.conversationReference = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conversationReference);

    t = new Timer(timerEvent);
    t.Change(30000, Timeout.Infinite);
    context.Wait<string>(NotificationDialogAfter);
}

public void timerEvent(object target)
{
    t.Dispose();
    ConversationStarter.Resume();
}
```

But the problem I have is that I'm interested in the result of this `NotifcationDialog` to know what the user wants to do next.
But all examples I found using proactive-messages do not regard the result of a proactive message with dialog:

```
public class ConversationStarter
{
    public static string conversationReference;

    public static async Task Resume()
    {
        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConversationReference>(conversationReference).GetPostToBotMessage();
        var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
        using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
        {
            var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
            await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();

            // here it seems only to be possible to call a dialog using Void
            var dialog = new NotificationDialog();
            task.Call(dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>(), null);

            await task.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

The `NotificationDialogAfter` handler should decide based on the user input which dialog to call next:

```
private async Task NotificationDialogAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    var whereToContinue = await result;

    if (whereToContinue.Equals("Start over"))
    {
        context.ClearAllConversationDataKeys();
        context.Call(new TagDialog(), this.TagDialogAfter);
    }
    else if (whereToContinue == "Tell friends")
    {
        context.Call(new TellFriendsDialog(), TellFriendsDialogAfter);
    }
    else if (whereToContinue == "Feedback")
    {
        context.Call(new FeedbackDialog(), this.FeedbackDialogAfter);
    }
}
```

So what I basically want is that the result of the `NotificationDialog` is forwarded to the `NotificationDialogAfter` handler which the Root dialog is waiting for.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Please provide the rest of the code.  It is difficult to follow what you have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by defining static continue handlers (in `GlobalContinueHandler`), that I can provide inside the NotificationDialog, when calling other dialogs.

```
[Serializable]
public class NotificationDialog : IDialog<string>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, Resume, new List<string> { "yes", "no" },
            "Found what you're looking for?");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task Resume(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        if (message == "yes")
        {
            context.Call(new SignupDialog(), GlobalContinueHandler.SignupDialogAfter);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Call(new FeedbackDialog(), GlobalContinueHandler.FeedbackDialogAfter);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really not fan of this solution but for now it seems to work.